# "undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented" error when loading psycopg2 module

Tags: python, django, wsgi, psycopg2

```
environment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
build Python 2.7.2 with ./configure --with-zlib --enable-unicode=ucs4
postgresql-9.0
wsgi
Django 1.3
virtualenv
apache
```

I am trying to build Ubuntu Django App Server. The installation completed with no error message. The exact installation method was successful with Ubuntu 11.04. 
However, when installation is completed on Ubuntu 10.04 and try to load `psycopg2` from Django, I got the following error (I did not get this error on 11.04):

```
File "/home/nreeves/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: /home/nreeves/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: _PyObject_NextNotImplemented
```

My guess is that some linkage to library is incorrect... but I have no idea where to start... I have a following output - not sure if this will help you help me...

```
$ ldd /home/nreeves/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77da000)
libpq.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 (0xb7788000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb776f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7614000)
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb75cc000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb747a000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xb73c9000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0xb73c5000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xb7395000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0xb734e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77db000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb734a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7335000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xb7311000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xb7308000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xb7304000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb72f0000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xb72e3000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb72cb000)
libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.26 (0xb722f000)
libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/libtasn1.so.3 (0xb721e000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/libgcrypt.so.11 (0xb71ab000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb71a6000)
```

And the following command outputs:

```
$ ls -l  /usr/lib/libpq*

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 224904 2011-09-26 06:33 /usr/lib/libpq.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 2011-09-26 10:51 /usr/lib/libpq.so -> libpq.so.5.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 2011-09-26 10:51 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 150976 2011-09-26 06:33 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4
```

To me it appears that all is correct. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You mention 'wsgi' as a tag. If that means you are using Apache/mod_wsgi then be aware that mod_wsgi must be compiled against the same Python version/installation and you need to verify that mod_wsgi is picking up the same libpython.so at run time as it is mod_wsgi that dictates the Python library linked in.

Comment: Yes, i am using apache/mod_wsgi. Installed via apt-get. I will check the linked library and post back here. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction. Below is the output:
`$ ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so`
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00e3a000)
 libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00178000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0x00668000)
 .....
and my custom installation 2.7.2 is not linking to libpython2.6...
I will research for the recommended Python 2.7.2 installation for Ubuntu 10.04 LST
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Set LD_RUN_PATH as environment variable when building mod_wsgi with the variable set to the actual directory where correct .so resides. Some details are on the mod_wsgi site.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] Thanks to both patrys and Graham Dumpleton, it was clear that my custom build Python 2.7 and wsgi installation was wrong and critical library linking was absent.
Now the problem is resolved by following the instruction below resolved this issue.
Thanks to all smart and kind people who is sharing information.

1. Reinstall Python: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17841/will-python2-7-be-available-for-lucid-in-future
2. Then uninstall WSGI: `sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-wsgi`
3. Install WSGI: http://grok.zope.org/documentation/tutorial/installing-and-setting-up-grok-under-mod-wsgi/installing-and-configuring-mod-wsgi

Answer (score 1):

This particular symbol comes from `libpython*.*.so.1.0` (replace wildcards with your version of python). You should see it when listing dynamic symbols using `nm`:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so | grep libpython
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fe14f0c6000)
$ nm -D /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 | grep PyObject_NextNotImplemented
000000000008a880 T _PyObject_NextNotImplemented
```

Are you using a custom build? It seems your version of `_psycopg.so` is not linked to `libpython` at all.

Comment: Yes, I build on my own... with 2 options specified in original post. and sure is, libpython is missing...
$ ldd venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so | grep libpython
>> doesn't return anything.... Strangely enough my Ubuntu 11.04 installation doesn't link to libpython neither though it is working... though I understand that it has to do with how python was built... I will research a bit more and figure it out the correct way to build/install and will post update here

Comment: As pointed out in my response the .so is linked to mod_wsgi. So you need to do ldd mod_wsgi.so. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Lack_Of_Python_Shared_Library